# SignInSchemes besides CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have used the following successfully in my Razor application:

```
authenticationBuilder.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
     options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

     // Other Options....
```

It creates an encrypted cookie in the browser and lets me persist the Access Token and JWT for a given user on their side (browser).

But now I am building a WebAPI service (Using .NET Core 3.1).  This service will be calling other web services.  It will use the OpenID Connect Client Credentials 
flow to get an access token to send to those "other web services".

This question is about how to persist the Client Credentials access token (So I don't have to go ask for it on each and every call.)

I don't feel that a cookie is the right way to persist this data.  I am not even sure that a WebAPI service will work with cookies (I have always heard of them as a browser thing).  I could, of course, just use an in-memory cache to store this.  I could also just make the call to to my IDP manually via an `HttpClient`.  But I would prefer to use the .Net Core framework, if it is setup for this situation.

**Are there other options for `OpenIdConnectOptions.SignInScheme` in the .Net Core 3.1 Framework?  If so what are they and how are they used?**

Comment: Edited your question for readability but not sure what ⭧ is supposed to represent?

Comment: @stuartd - shows up as a diagonal up and right arrow on my screen... I am guessing not on yours?  (I will see if I can find a better way to show that as your change does not represent what I was trying to convey.)

Comment: Ah, it was showing as a 'box' for me. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to sign in, the authentication handler for the schema needs to implement `IAuthenticationSignInHandler`.

As per the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.signinauthenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [github search](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/search?q=IAuthenticationSignInHandler&unscoped_q=IAuthenticationSignInHandler), `CookieAuthenticationHandler` is the only handler that concretely implements the interface. So my *assumption* is there's no other built-in sign-in handlers out of the box.

*[`PolicySchemeHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/PolicySchemeHandler.cs) implements the interface but forwards authentication to another schema.*

Also, take a look at [ASP.NET Core Data Protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) if you need to protect access tokens.